# Compilation error attempting to use `min()` function in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to write an extension for the Swift `Int` type to save nested `min()/max()` functions. It looks like this:

```
extension Int {
    func bound(minVal: Int, maxVal: Int) -> Int {
        let highBounded = min(self, maxVal)
        return max(minVal, highBounded)
    }
}
```

However, I have a compilation error when assigning/computing `highBounded`:

`IntExtensions.swift:13:25: 'Int' does not have a member named 'min'`

Why aren't the functions defined by the standard library properly located?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like it is trying to find a method in Int for min() and max() since you are extending Int. You can get around this and use the default min and max functions by specifying the Swift namespace.

```
extension Int {
    func bound(minVal: Int, maxVal: Int) -> Int {
        let highBounded = Swift.min(self, maxVal)
        return Swift.max(minVal, highBounded)
    }
}
```